# php ajax dynamic content

Tags: php, ajax

Does anybody know how to make text appear between two lines of text(So the bottom text slides down slowly to make room). Using php and ajax? no flash!

ie

some text here

some text here

click and then:

some text here

more here
more here

some text here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, add a click-event.  Untested:

```
$(".clickMeForSlideDown").click(function() {
    $("#divThatWillSlideDown").slideDown("slow");
});
```

More complete example and documentation [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideDown).